# (in Video.js) how to set custom request headers?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, http-headers, html5-video, video.js

After running into this problem, I worked up a minimal example based on [this documentation](https://github.com/videojs/http-streaming#hlsxhr):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.4.1/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- ^^ video.js stylesheet ^^ -->
<title>Video.JS test</title>
</head>
<body>
<video autoplay controls id="player"
       poster="http://localhost:21212/img/tzGk0I0eb-4"
       class="video-js">
  <source src="http://localhost:21212/vid/tzGk0I0eb-4">
</video>

<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.4.1/video.js"></script>
<!-- ^^ video.js script ^^ -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  var headers = videojs.Hls.xhr.headers || {}
  headers['X-Arbitrary'] = 'some-arbitrary-header-text'
  videojs.Hls.xhr.headers = headers
  var player = videojs('player')
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I also tried it with this JS (I forget where I saw this):

```
videojs.Hls.xhr.beforeRequest = options => {
console.log(options)
var headers = options.headers || {}
headers['X-Arbitrary'] = 'some-arbitrary-header-text'
options.headers = headers
return options
}
var player = videojs('player')
```

As well as this (documented [here](https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-videojs.html#xhr) ):

```
videojs.xhr({
headers: {
'X-Arbitrary': 'some-arbitrary-text'
}
})
var player = videojs('player')
```

And this ( from [here](https://github.com/naugtur/xhr#optionsbeforesend) )

```
videojs.Hls.xhr.beforeSend = request => {
requst.setRequestHeader('X-Arbitrary', 'some-arbitrary-text')
}
var player = videojs('player')
```

I have a mock server which outputs the request information:

```
2019-01-03 17:11:56 -05:00 :: GET -> 200:: "/img/tzGk0I0eb-4"
Host:
- localhost:21212
User-Agent:
- Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0
Accept:
- */*
Accept-Language:
- en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding:
- gzip, deflate
DNT:
- 1
Connection:
- keep-alive
Pragma:
- no-cache
Cache-Control:
- no-cache
2019-01-03 17:11:56 -05:00 :: GET -> 200:: "/vid/tzGk0I0eb-4"
Host:
- localhost:21212
User-Agent:
- Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0
Accept:
- video/webm,video/ogg,video/*;q=0.9,application/ogg;q=0.7,audio/*;q=0.6,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language:
- en-US,en;q=0.5
Range:
- bytes=0-
DNT:
- 1
Connection:
- keep-alive
Pragma:
- no-cache
Cache-Control:
- no-cache
2019-01-03 17:11:56 -05:00 :: GET -> 200:: "/img/tzGk0I0eb-4"
Host:
- localhost:21212
User-Agent:
- Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0
Accept:
- */*
Accept-Language:
- en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding:
- gzip, deflate
DNT:
- 1
Connection:
- keep-alive
Pragma:
- no-cache
Cache-Control:
- no-cache
2019-01-03 17:11:56 -05:00 :: GET -> 200:: "/img/tzGk0I0eb-4"
Host:
- localhost:21212
User-Agent:
- Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0
Accept:
- */*
Accept-Language:
- en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding:
- gzip, deflate
DNT:
- 1
Connection:
- keep-alive
Pragma:
- no-cache
Cache-Control:
- no-cache
```

All of the examples output similar log entries, without the requested header.

Comment: I never did find a solution to this or get it working as intended. My workaround was to put the custom header value in a query parameter instead of a header.

Answer (score 0):

Pass them as query parameters. Apparently this solves the problem when other approaches fail and it is considered safe, like [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32722952/is-it-safe-to-put-a-jwt-into-the-url-as-a-query-parameter-of-a-get-request) about passing JWTSs in query params.